WSO2 Large File Handling
I have an API built on WSO2 that accepts a file (size between 35 and 50 MB) and forwards it to a third-party system.
In my experience with MuleSoft, I could enable streaming to handle large files without doing any data transformation to avoid performance overhead. I am looking for a similar approach in WSO2 where I don’t need to transform the data.
However, I have heard that WSO2 has a file size limit of 10–12 MB, which I assume applies when performing tasks like file reading or data transformation. Can anyone confirm if there is a way to handle larger file uploads, perhaps through streaming or another method, within WSO2? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

You can handle large files using FileConnector while specifying the streaming =true parameter.
How to use it
